# Helm Rollback Behavior in Kubernetes: Pipeline Status Confusion

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

**Issue Description:**
When deploying changes to a Kubernetes cluster using Helm, a safety mechanism is implemented. If a pod experiences a crash loop that lasts for 300 seconds, Helm triggers an automatic rollback to the previous deployment version. While this rollback mechanism is designed to maintain system stability, it can introduce confusion in certain scenarios.

This command:

**helm upgrade --install -f values.yaml  . --atomic --timeout 300s**

The concern arises when, after a successful rollback, a subsequent deployment attempt encounters issues and fails. In such cases, the CI/CD pipeline may still be marked as successful, despite the fact that Helm executed a rollback due to the failure of the deployment. This behavior can lead to confusion among users and stakeholders, as they might not immediately realize that a rollback occurred due to deployment failures.

The objective of this issue is to discuss and explore potential improvements to Helm's rollback reporting and pipeline status handling to ensure greater clarity and accuracy in conveying deployment outcomes. This would help users quickly and accurately identify when a rollback was triggered and whether the overall deployment was successful or not.

**Proposed Solution:**

1. Enhance Helm's reporting capabilities to explicitly communicate when a rollback is initiated due to a deployment failure.
2. Implement a mechanism to update the CI/CD pipeline status based on the outcome of both the rollback and subsequent deployment attempts.
3. Provide informative notifications to users and stakeholders about the status changes, ensuring that they are promptly informed about any rollbacks and deployment failures.

This improvement will lead to a more transparent and user-friendly deployment process, reducing confusion and facilitating better incident management.

The objective of this issue is to discuss and explore potential improvements to Helm's rollback reporting and pipeline status handling to ensure greater clarity and accuracy in conveying deployment outcomes. This would help users quickly and accurately identify when a rollback was triggered and whether the overall deployment was successful or not.

Suggest any way if we can handle this use case

Comment: I'm not clear what programming-related question you're asking.  Do you need a specific change in your CI pipeline code (in which case it would help to [edit] the question to show what you have now)?  Are you trying to make a feature request for Helm (better asked on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/helm/helm))?

Comment: When deploying changes to a Kubernetes cluster using Helm, a safety mechanism is in place. If a pod enters a crash loop for a duration of 300 seconds, it triggers an automatic rollback to the previous version. 
However, it's essential to note that in some cases, after a successful rollback, if the subsequent deployment attempt fails, the CI/CD pipeline may still be marked as successful. This can lead to confusion for users as they may not immediately realize that Helm executed a rollback due to a failed deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed that when we're deploying changes to our application using Helm in a Kubernetes cluster, there's a safety mechanism in place. If a pod enters a crash loop for a continuous period of 300 seconds, it triggers an automatic rollback to the previous version.

`helm upgrade --install -f values.yaml <release-name> . --atomic --timeout 300s`

However, it's crucial to be aware that sometimes, even after a successful rollback, if the subsequent deployment attempt fails, the pipeline may still be marked as successful. This can be confusing for users as they may not immediately realize that Helm executed a rollback due to a failed deployment.

So I have used custom script for resolve & handling above issue

```html
   helm upgrade --install -f values.yaml {{Release_name}} . --wait --timeout {{timeout}}
      #Get Status code
      helm_upgrade_exit_status=$?
      echo 'Helm release failed with EXIT_CODE: '$helm_upgrade_exit_status''
      # Check the Helm upgrade/install status
      if [ $helm_upgrade_exit_status -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Helm upgrade/install successful...."
      else
        #If helm release failed than rollback
        echo "Helm upgrade/install failed. Rolling back pervious version..."
        
        # Perform the Helm rollback
        helm  rollback {{Release_name}}  0 --wait --timeout {{timeout}}
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "Helm rollback completed..."
          echo "Action Required: Check your deployment  on k8s cluster why it Rollbacked"         
          # Exit with a non-zero status code to indicate pipeline failure
          exit 1
        else
          echo "Helm Rollback also failed ..."
          exit 1
        fi
      fi
```